# Route fragments nomenclature

Tags: rest, routes

Given a route /users/1234/comments, what are these called?

```
/
/users
/users/1234
/users/1234/comments
```

Subroutes, parent routes, route fragments?

Answer (score 1):

I would call them `relationship routes` or `sub-collections`.

You can have a deep dive by reading this: http://restful-api-design.readthedocs.org/en/latest/relationships.html

> As we have seen in Resources, the resource is the fundamental unit in 
>   RESTful API design. Resources model objects from the application data
>   model.
>
> Resources do not exist in isolation, but have relationships to other
>   other resources. Sometimes these relationships exist between the
>   mapped objects in the application data model as well, sometimes they
>   are specific to the RESTful resources.
>
> One of the principles of the RESTful architecture style is that these
>   relationships are expressed by hyperlinks to the representation of a
>   resource.
>   ...